# How to ssh and scp to Condor using Python

Tags: python, ssh, pip, scp, pexpect

I am trying to scp a zip folder to a Condor submit node using scp. I have looked into several ways of doing this such as using the subprocess module and others. Based on what I've seen on various sources, I've been advised that using pexpect is the best way forward to achieve this.

I am trying to install pexpect using by:

```
    pip install pexpect;
```

And this error is shown:

```
   transport, pw = yield from asyncio.get_event_loop()\
                         ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If it helps, I am running 2.7.6 on the Windows 10 bash linux terminal.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: The async parts of pexpect rely on Python 3. What, exactly, were you doing when you got that error?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for responding. I literally just typed pip install pexpect into my shell.